# Standalone Calendar App/Software

Tags: calendar

We're looking for a standalone (non-cms) calendaring solution to display on the web.  It could be open source or a paid service.

We're primarily looking for a way to display a calendar on the web complete with when the events are and what the names of the events are.  It would be great if it can display in different views like by week, month, year.  Month view would be the most important one.  We want to keep it as simple as possible.  We mainly just want users to view the calendar.  The events do not even have to be editable on the end user's side just as long as there is some way for us on the backend to add/delete/import events into the calendar whether it be through .ics (iCal files)/desktop software/via some web interface.  We know Google Calendar is around and there is also PHPiCalendar.  Are there any other alternatives around?

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty cool calendar built on jQuery.

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

Answer (score 0):

Laszlo Webtop has a cool calendar app:

http://www.laszlosystems.com/products/webtop/webtop_nexxus

Answer (score 0):

WebCalendar, WebIcal